# CloverETL Transaction Blocks for Temporary Tables

Tags: postgresql, etl

I am attempting to build an ETL script in the CloverETL Designer that, as part of its processing, builds a temporary table that it then uses it in a join.  For reasons specific to the system a temp table that does not last outside of the transaction block is ideal, and so I am trying to avoid creating a view or standard table.  Connections are being made over a JDBC driver to the databases involved.

I already know the SQL for both the temporary table and the query that follows using that table.

I am not, however, entirely sure what the best way is to do this under CloverETL.  Can I get a DBExecute to run in the same transaction block as a DBInputTable? Is my best bet going to be to bring both tables into the local database and then work with them from there?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Clover components work in the same transaction you need to specify *threadSafeConnection="false"*. By default this parameter is set to *true*, so each component uses its own connection instance for working with database. You can a find few topics on CloverETL forum, that describe the problem in details, eg: 
http://forum.cloveretl.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3342
http://forum.cloveretl.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3431